# I am getting below error while trying to deploy using apex deploy

Tags: java, node.js

```
Error: function hello: InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs6.10 is 
no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the 
new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions.
status code: 400, request id: 38a22cfb-99f3-43dd-a64xxxxxxx
```

I created the project using apex init and trying to deploy but getting above error.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Actually, the error message is already telling you what is going wrong.

Comment: i mean how can i solve this error

Comment: as the error message suggests: "We recommend you use the 
new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions."